# Power BI Sort - Hiding the sort Column

Tags: powerbi, dax

In a Power BI table, I am trying to sort a table visual with a sort column which is average orders per customer. The data in the FACT table is at order level. When I try to hid the sort column in the table visual, I change the column name from Average orders per Customer to *, lock the filter and hide it and then pull the lines in so the column appears hidden. However due to the size of the contents of sort column ( row values) like 28878, this means the rows get fatter and it looks weird as the row height is blown up. Is there a way in Power BI to sort a table visual without having to add the sort column to it or a way where the rows go not get bigger due to the contents of the hidden sort column ( settings) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your last question, you can turn off the auto-sizing of the column in the Format panel on your visual.

[image: Format Panel]

You probably want Word wrap off too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a white shape to cover the undesired column:

1. Insert > Shapes
2. Format Shape > turn off Fill and Outline
3. Format > use Bring forward or Send backward to get the shape covering the visualization.